# .NET memory not getting released for a long time

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I have a .NET 6 WinForms app and in that I have a form that loads 300MB of data each time (that's a separate problem). If I open and close the form over and over, the memory builds up and quickly gets into GBs, with one user surpassing 8GB. Combine that with the fact that this is on a shared server and we are having serious RAM issues.

I've been investigating a memory leak and have been using `dotnet-counters` to watch the GC Heap Size, but it doesn't decrease much when the form is closed. So, yeah, it seems like there is a memory leak there, but the weird thing is that after 15-30 minutes, the memory may decrease after all.

What would make the heap decrease in size after a long period of being idle?

Comment: If you have loads of RAM why would it ever release it? GC only releases memory if there is memory pressure. Maybe set a Heap Limit for GC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#heap-limit

Comment: See [8 Ways You can Cause Memory Leaks in .NET](https://michaelscodingspot.com/ways-to-cause-memory-leaks-in-dotnet/) and [Debug a memory leak in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak).

Comment: GC won't clear memory if it thinks that there are still viable references to those objects. Ensure that any objects that gather your data blocks are properly disposed of.

Comment: @Charlieface I never said we have loads of RAM. While we have been adding RAM, we've seen the available RAM go to zero and had subsequent OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: Without code, it's hard to give an answer. If you open and close the form fast enough but memory eventually frees, it's possible you're experiencing memory *pressure* not a memory leak.

Comment: @Charlieface Also, I could understand the app not giving the working set memory back to the OS if it didn't need to, but if the objects on the heap can be released, that's what GC is there for, right?

Comment: 300 Mb if allocated as single memory chunk should be placed into LOH which is not compacted that often (for performance reasons). If your app usage pattern involves quite a lot of such allocations and deallocations you can experience something looking as memory leak. You can try executing something like `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce; GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);`

Comment: I see two votes to close this with no feedback. I don't understand this as the final question is simple: "What would make the heap decrease in size after a long period of being idle?" That is a clear question that requires no code. Or if semantics are the problem "What would make _a_ heap decrease in size after a long period of being idle?"